# Local Applet Security Exception

Tags: java, applet, localhost

I'm trying to run a basic hello world Java applet in my browser, but I keep getting "Application Blocked by Security Settings" with the following message:

> SecurityException: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running

I tried changing the security settings through the [Java Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml), but there is no slider, just certificates.

I get the same error when trying to open the .html file in other browsers.

**Applet code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorldApp extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(label);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>    
<body>    
   <applet code="HelloWorldApp.class" width="300" height="100"></applet>    
</body>    
</html>
```

**Question**: How can I get the applet to work? Or rather, how can I change the security settings to allow the applet to run locally, if that is the issue and not something else?

Comment: Sounds more like a browser issue

Comment: Also, it doesn't run on all browsers that I have (i.e., Opera, Chrome, IE, FireFox, Safari). I get the same message.

Comment: 1) What do you see under the `Advanced` tab under the `Secure Execution Environment` leaf of the tree?  I see 7 check boxes with the 1st 6 checked. 2) What version of Java is installed there?

Comment: I have Java 6 SE. Under the Advanced tab I have a Security leaf. There I have have 16 boxes starting with "Allow user to grant permission to signed content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after deleting Java 6 and 7 and re-installing 7 and restarting the computer, it now works. Did not know I had to delete the older version even after I updated to 7 as I thought that was done automatically on update.

[This site](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Pogo/Solution-WINDOWS-Java-issues-step-by-step/m-p/393326/highlight/true#M14757) provided guidance. My bad for such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue today . The new Java has improved upon its security and the following [article](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html) talks about it in detail .

I am surprised that you didnt see the slider on your Java Control Panel . I was able to change the setting to `MEDIUM` from `HIGH` and then it works for me .

[Location of the Java Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml#control%20panel)

[Changing security settings using the Java Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Answer (score 0):

"Use a web server to test the examples in this lesson. The use of local applets is not recommended, and local applets are blocked when the security level setting in the Java Control Panel is set to High or Very High."