# Applet not running locally

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that no longer runs with my navigator although it runs perfectly well when i launch it as a stand alone application.

Previously i had JRE 6 and it ran well, now I'm using the latest versions. i have read about the new security improvements with the newer JRE versions 7 +.

This is my HTML code

```html
  <html><body>
  <p>
  <applet code="UI.class" archive="UI.jar"
  width="740" height="400"></applet>
  </p>
  </body></html>
```

I keep on getting a blockedException.
i am willing to upload my jar file if you tell me how to do it .

Comment: Just a heads up: Java applets won't reliably load in modern web browsers any more. Many browsers have disabled Java by default. Mac OS X no longer includes Java at all with the OS. If this is intended to be used for public consumption, you may want to consider an alternative.

Comment: @  Colin Morelli No, this is only to be used on a private network !

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question [has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072814/local-applet-security-exception).

So it seems that uninstalling JDK6 and 7 and then reinstalling JDK7 could solve your problem.

If it doesn't work you can still [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) your jar with a command like this `jarsigner jar-file alias`. (It is possible to do it from Maven or Ant)

You can also modify the [policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) file of you JDK.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html) is a page explaining how to do this.

If you like to do it manually, here is what the content should look like:

```
grant  {
    permission java.security.AllPermission; // All permissions are granted 
};
```